Need iBeacon capable of lower TX power than -20 dBm
I've got an application using beacons for location/proximity.  I've looked at a lot of beacons, and so far none of the currently available beacons I can find allow setting the TX power for the beacon below -20 dBm.  I need to deploy beacons relatively closely together, and at -20 dBm the minimum distance I can reliably get is 30 feet without flipping back and forth between adjacent beacons.
To be clear, I'm looking for a finished product, but if anyone can even point at a chipset capable of lower TX power, I can try to track down a beacon using it.
Nordic Semiconductor used to have a chipset that allowed -40 dBm, but I need a continuing supply of these beacons and no one I've identified seems to be making new beacons with a setting lower than -20 dBm.  All vendors seem to be concentrating on making the beacons detectable further away.

Have you tried putting obstructions?  Maybe try wrapping one in tinfoil.

These get deployed in a customer environment, so wrapping in tinfoil couldn't be a final working solution, but I have actually played with tinfoil, internal metal foil tape, and rigid metal barriers.  None of the 3 does what I need.  If they didn't need to be off the shelf, I've considered trying to mutilate/modify the antenna on the circuit board, but that's not a workable answer either for our deployment environment.

Silicon Labs has the EFR32BG12, which goes down to -30 dBm. Is that low enough, or do you need lower?
